# CentOS - Configure "shared gateway" for secondary IP range?

Tags: networking, centos, shared, routes, gateway

I have two /28 IP ranges assigned to our server.  The second IP range is configured exactly the same as the first range, but won't route to the server.  Contacted the host and they said I need to,

> "configure them to use the gateway from your primary range as a shared gateway".

I unfortunately have no clue what that means, and Google searches came up with nothing.  I'm thinking it may have something to do with the `/etc/iproute2/` directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

This is a fairly common networking practice. Your provider has set up some sort of route on their end of the secondary /28 subnet they provided to you. Traffic destined to that secondary range will be routed across to your interface with them (preferably) or to an IP address on the primary IP range. Your server should be configured with a single default route, so if you have configured a second default route that would be incorrect. As long as this is all configured on a single interface (i.e. eth0), the server will make sure that traffic destined to or sourced from the secondary IP range will go back through the default route in your primary IP range. That is what they mean by "shared gateway."

There should not be any reason to touch anything in the /etc/iproute2/ directory.

See this forum post for configuration examples: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7949

-Ben